# Cleaning up HTML created by contentEditable in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

I've written a document editor which uses contentEditable to create HTML content. In some larger documents the style of syntax seems is all over the place. This is most likely a result of content pasted in from wordpad and earlier versions of the editor.

The problem is, now I'm left with a lot of very inconsistent documents.

It starts off fairly normal. Simple `<p>` tags for each line

```
<p>It is a truth</p>
<p>universally acknowledged</p>
<p>that a single&nbsp;man</p>
```

The only "bad" html up to this point is a few empty `<i></i>` tags, and the occasional `&nbsp;` instead of whitespace (anyone know why?)

Then it about halfway down the document, the line breaks switched to this format.

```
<div>
    <br>
    CHAPTER 1<br>
    <br>
    The sky above the port
    <br>
    was the color of a television
    <br>
    tuned to a dead channel.
</div> 
<div>
    <br>
</div>
```

Then about 3/4 down the page, we get this. It seems to have reverted to `<p></p>` tags, but now embeds them randomly in `<span>` tags with empty `lang` attributes

```
<div>
    <span lang="">
        <p>It was the best of times,</p> 
        <p>it was the worst of times,</p> 
    </span>
    <p>it was the age of wisdom,</p>
    <p>it was the age of foolishness,</p>
</div>
```

Note: some lines are inside a `<span>`, others are outside.

Worse, later on we get nested `<span>` tags

```
<span lang="">
    <div>
        <span lang="EN-GB">
            <p>Stately, plump </p> 
            <p>Buck Mulligan came </p> 
            <span lang="EN-GB">
                <p>from the stairhead, </p>
                <p>bearing a bowl of lather </p>                
                <span lang="EN-GB">
                    <p> on which a mirror and a razor lay crossed</p>
                </span>
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>
</span>
```

You may also notice the parentage of the `<span>` and `<div>` tags is now reversed at the outset, with the `<div>` now a child of the `<span>`

I've noticed other oddities. `<i></i>` is used at the start but later `<em></em>` is used.

1. What's the best way to clean this HTML up?
2. Should I try and surround orphaned lines with `<p>` tags?
3. How do I remove only those `<div>` tags which contain `<p>` tags themselves? And how do I avoid leaving orphaned text in the document?

Answer (score 1):

is a hard question, I had the same problem editing HTML from texts.

I found out this free pure HTML + JS editor: TinyMCE

http://www.tinymce.com/

which includes cleaning text options, you can choose the tags you want to clean from the text.

Is very powerful if you have the chance to change the editor you are using.

Comment: TinyMCE in a great html editor. I normally use CKEditor with asp.net webforms. It has a great usercontrol. Despite of that both are great HTML editor. My tip: disable the paste html feature on them, this can save from a lot of trouble.